# BarCode is not displaying on pdf using Apache fop

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We are facing one issue in barcode generation. Barcode is not showing on pdf and throwing exception

Please find below code

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
            <barcode:barcode xmlns:barcode="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns"
                             message="HELLO WORLD">
                <barcode:code128>
                    <barcode:height>15mm</barcode:height>
                </barcode:code128>
            </barcode:barcode>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext-complete</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error:
Image not available. URI: (instream-object). Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for null (No context info available).

Please help me, what is causing issue.

Thanks in Advance

Best Regards
RKG

Comment: Have you followed the stack trace? Looks like it tries to load an image but the ref is null.

Comment: This is version issue, i have upgraded version to 2.1 and working fine.<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext-complete</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Version 2.1 works fine? Are you forced to use 2.0? Maybe file a bug report then.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the discussion over it here 
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.fop.user/36178

You must be using barcode4j-fop-ext-complete.jar which is missing barcode-xgc.jar files.

You can download the updated fop barcode4j jar files here :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/barcode4j/files/

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
Upgrading version solved my problem

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j-fop-ext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```